# Auto-forwarding emails to 2 email addresses

Tags: gmail

Can I auto-forward emails to multiple addresses in Gmail? Or if I create a group, can forward my emails to that address?

Comment: See this Google Apps script on my GitHub: https://github.com/JeisonSanches/Gmail-Auto-Multiple-Forward/

Answer (score 28):

You can also use filters to do this. [This page](http://www.nordicblueconsulting.com/forward-emails-multiple-recipients-gmail-google-apps#.UtWI17TAhEg) has the details which I'll copy below.

> **Create a filter to forward Emails to multiple accounts:**
>
> 1. Access your Gmail web interface (mail.google.com) and find the little gear in the top right-hand corner and left click it.
> 2. Left click on settings
> 3. Find the blue navigation items, across the top, and click on “Forwarding and POP/IMAP”
> 4. Click on the **Add a forwarding address** button
> 5. Enter in the Email address that you would like to forward the Emails to
> 6. Google will send a verification Email, to the address chosen, so you will have to log into the account you added and click the link in
>    the Email to verify the Email address.
> 7. Repeat steps 4 through 6 for all Email addresses you are forwarding to
> 8. Access the settings again, with steps 1 and 2, but this time select the “filters” navigation item
> 9. Click the link to “*Create a new filter*”
> 10. In the **size** fields, set them to greater than 0 bytes to catch everything. Now click the link “*Create filter with this search*”
> 11. In the next box that opens, Select the Forward it to: and choose (from a droplist) your first address to forward the Emails to. Don’t
>     worry, we will add the rest momentarily
> 12. Click the link again “*Create filter with this search*” and you will be returned to the filters main screen
> 13. Repeat steps 9 through 12 to add in all the other Email recipients and keep all the settings the same

Comment: I just found a situation where broadcast emails were not forwarded because "my" address does not appear in the To: field. You can specify a wildcard (*) in the To: address so I've changed my filter to use this instead of specify what I think the To: field should contain.

Comment: Not ideal because of plus addressing and aliases.

Comment: Feedback on solution: Change point 5 ( Enter in the Email address that you would like to forward the Emails to ) Do NOT enter in the email address of the email you want in the filter "To" field.
Just enter " * " As Michael pointed out:
I just found a situation where broadcast emails were not forwarded because "my" address does not appear in the To: field. You can specify a wildcard (*) in the To: address so I've changed my filter to use this instead of specify what I think the To: field should contain. Proved a very useful solution.

Comment: Best criterion for the filter, is "size > 0 bytes" - catches everything

Comment: I was using `to:({email}@gmail.com)` before, but seems like `size > 0 bytes` is the best approach

Answer (score 1):

If you want to forward your emails to multiple email addresses, you can set up a POP account for the accounts looking to receive the forwarded emails. To do this, login to the account that you want to forward the emails to and do the following;

1. Click on the settings cog in the top right and click Settings
2. Click on Forwarding and POP/IMAP and enable POP
3. Now click on Accounts and Add a POP3 mail account you own
4. You can then fill out the credentials of your choice and ultimately forward to multiple emails addresses

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier method which works fine for me so far. I used a Chrome plugin to add "auto Bcc" functionality to Gmail, and it supports multiple email accounts set up. I can use one Bcc address for my Salesforce account, one Bcc address for my company account and no Bcc on my personal account.

It's free, and worth a try: [Auto Bcc for Gmail™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-bcc-for-gmail/hfjgikgjcgdhlklibkcobckkhklaeodd)

[image: auto bcc]